# Setup netbeans for OGRE on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, netbeans, ubuntu, ogre3d, ogre

I read [Setting Up An Application - NetBeans - Linux](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Setting+Up+An+Application+-+NetBeans+-+Linux) in Ogre tutorials. But this instructs to build the project separately on console using make && make install. It seems Netbeans is only used as a editor. Is there a way to I do everything using Netbeans?

I tried to setup Netbeans to use OGRE libraries, but it was not successful. I get some errors when I build the project. This is what I did so far.

> Project properties > C++ Compiler : Include Directories
>
> /usr/include/OGRE:/usr/include/OIS:/usr/include
>
> In Linker : I added all the
>   libogre*.so files in /usr/lib as
>   Libraries.

I used apt-get to install OGRE

```
pkg-config --libs OGRE 
  -lOgreMain -lpthread 

pkg-config --cflags OGRE
-pthread -I/usr/include/OGRE
```

This [link](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/NetBeans+6.9.1&structure=Development) only provides details for doing this on windows.
Could someone tell me how to setup Netbeans for OGRE correctly on Linux

**UPDATE**
The console output

```
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/carrace build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/TutorialApplication.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/BaseApplication.o -L/usr/bin -lPlugin_BSPSceneManager -lPlugin_CgProgramManager -lPlugin_OctreeSceneManager -lPlugin_OctreeZone -lPlugin_ParticleFX -lPlugin_PCZSceneManager -lRenderSystem_GL -lOgreMain -lOgrePaging -lOgreProperty -lOgreRTShaderSystem -lOgreTerrain -lOIS-1.3.0 -lOIS -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_date_time -lboost_serialization-mt -lboost_serialization -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_thread -lboost_wserialization-mt -lboost_wserialization 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPlugin_BSPSceneManager
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPlugin_CgProgramManager
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPlugin_OctreeSceneManager
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPlugin_OctreeZone
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPlugin_ParticleFX
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPlugin_PCZSceneManager
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRenderSystem_GL
```

I tried adding these folders separately but it didn't work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The preprocessor definitions are for windows and can be skipped. Otherwise it looks pretty good. What errors are you getting? Without details it's hard to debug things

Comment: @Jay Sorry for the late reply. Some libraries are missing, I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked with

```
-lOgreMain -lOgreTerrain -lOIS -lpthread
```

as linker options

and the same includes as you have

Answer (score 0):

You forgot pkg-config --ldflags OGRE

Answer (score 0):

You can see my tutorial in here http://arief-rublog.blogspot.com/2011/09/cara-pengaturan-ogre-dengan-ide.html , but my tutorial in Bahasa Indonesia, may be you can use google translate to translate it. i hope my tutorial is useful for you.

Comment: I'm not involved with this project anymore so I have no way of testing your answer. Anyways thank you.
If you could have an english translation too, I think it will be very helpful to many people and will be easy to find on search engines.

Comment: I wonder why this answer is down voted? I did a qiuck check with google translater(gave me an understandable translation), and the content seems legitimate. Is it the language?

Comment: Bahasa Indonesia in google translate you can choose Indonesian, sorry for my worst.

Comment: Bahasa Indonesia in google translate you can choose Indonesian to english, sorry for my worst.